# How to extract and sort ping times from text file into another text file/list

Tags: text-processing, sort

I have a log file that contains the pings from a certain website in a text file called `pingoutput.txt` separating each ping reply by line. Now I need to extract from this text file the round-trip time in between `time=` and `ms` into either another text file or list that I could then sort smallest to largest.

```
64 bytes from onofri.org (67.222.36.105): icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=202 ms
64 bytes from onofri.org (67.222.36.105): icmp_req=2 ttl=47 time=206 ms
64 bytes from onofri.org (67.222.36.105): icmp_req=3 ttl=47 time=215 ms
```

Also the `pingoutput.txt` file is large and has about 86400 lines. I'm doing this through a shell script on Linux.

Comment: With GNU `grep`: `grep -Po 'time=\K\d+' file | sort -n`

Comment: 86K lines hasn't been large in several decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
sed 's/.*time=\([0-9]*\) .*/\1/' times | sort -n > outfile
```

Where `times` is this file:

```
cat times 
64 bytes from onofri.org (67.222.36.105): icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=202 ms
64 bytes from onofri.org (67.222.36.105): icmp_req=2 ttl=47 time=206 ms
64 bytes from onofri.org (67.222.36.105): icmp_req=3 ttl=47 time=215 ms
```

And `outfile` looks like this:

```
cat outfile 
202
206
215
```

Comment: If you do not put -n option in the sort, if you have times under 100 ms it will not sort properly.

Comment: @Rob Oops! Thanks for pointing this out. Edited as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the time with this sample script:

```
awk -F\= '{print int($4)}' pingoutput.txt
```

It use = as delimiter and use int function to get only the numbers of "202 ms" string

To redirect output to other file use command:

```
awk -F\= '{print int($4)}' pingoutput.txt > times.txt
```

For sorting the output you can pipe output of awk to sort command

```
awk -F\= '{print int($4)}' pingoutput.txt |sort -n > times.txt
```

Comment: Amazing, but I see its printing, how could I send the time to a list or different text file instead of just printing?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Perl regex and grep

```
grep -oP '(?<=time\=).*' pingoutput
```

Comment: Probably it is better to use `\S+` instead of `.*`, so that you just get the digits (everything up to the space).

Answer (score 1):

The main tools for this sort of work are `sed` and `awk`. They are designed to read a pipe or file line by line and transform it.

Example sed solution:

```
  sed 's/.* time=\([0-9]*\) ms/\1/' pingoutput.txt
```

Should output:

```
  202
  206
  215
```

Breakdown of the `s/.* time=\([0-9]*\) ms/\1/`:

`s` means you want to do a substitution command. Substitution commands have the pattern `s/<pattern to match>/<replacement pattern>/`.

The `<pattern to match>` is `.* time=\([0-9]*\) ms`

The `.` is any character. The `*` says that any character can appear zero or more times. This is to consume all characters up until the `time=` part of the line.

The `\( \)` part defines what is called a group. Whatever is matched by the pattern in between the parentheses will be sorted in a group named 1 since there is only one group in our pattern.

The part inside the `\( \)` is `[0-9]*`, which says match any character between the character `0` and the character `9` (all digits), and again the `*` means there could be zero or more. This will match the number you are interested in.

Finally we have `ms` at the end to consume it from the line.

The `<replacement pattern>` is just `\1`; this means you want to replace the entire matched string with what was captured by group #1 in the match pattern.

You can do it with `awk` too; I recommend learning how to use both tools.

Addition:

To sort the value numerically you need to stream the results using the '|' into the sort tool. But in order to make sure the times are sorted numerically you want to use `sort -n`, otherwise you can get a weird sorting order.

```
sed 's/.* time=\([0-9]*\) ms/\1/' pingoutput.txt | sort -n
```

**Further Addition to support decimal numbers**

```
sed 's/.* time=\([0-9]*\(\.[0-9]*\)\{0,1\}\) ms/\1/' pingoutput.txt | sort -n
```

What I did was add a optional part that describes the decimal part of the number within the group that was \([0-9]*\) I added:

Anther sub group that can appear 0 or 1 time only that is described by \(\)\{0,1\} the part in {} the first number is the minimum occurrence the second number maximum.
The pattern inside that group is \.[0-9]* the reason we have to but \ in from of the '.' is that otherwise as you know now '.' means any character so for it to only allow a '.' you have to escape it with \

Comment: I just realized some of my values may contain decimals for example 12.6 ms. will the 0-9 limiter ignore the decimal point? Is there any way to take in that entire value now and still sort?

Comment: Updating solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `pcre` option with `grep`

```
$ grep -oP 'time=\K\d+' pingout.txt 
202
206
215
$ grep -oP 'time=\K\d+' pingout.txt | sort -n
202
206
215
$ grep -oP 'time=\K\d+' pingout.txt | sort -nr
215
206
202
```

- `time=\K` [positive lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind#t=201609281409228526024) the string `time=` - this is not part of output
- `\d+` one or more digits, can also use `[^ ]+` to extract characters other than space

To save the output to a file, use the `>` redirection

```
$ grep -oP 'time=\K\d+' pingout.txt | sort -n > op.txt
$ cat op.txt 
202
206
215
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[ =]' '{ print $11 }' logfile
```

If `0 ms` ping times never occur, we can "golf" it:

```
awk -F[\ =] '$0=$11'
```

If there is a column 11, `$0` gets a non-blank, non-zero value. Such a value is Boolean true, triggering the action. The action is missing so the default action is `{ print }`, which means `{ print $0 }`.

The regular expression `[ =]` matches an equal sign or space, and with `-F` we install that as the `FS` variable: Awk's field separator. Each line of input is broken into fields by removing a space or equal sign. The fields are the pieces of the line which remain around these separators (even if empty: two consecutive spaces will have a field between them).  Under this separation, it turns out that the ping times end up in the 11th column, and so we use the `$` parameter access operator with argument `11` to refer to it.

If zeros occur, we can still golf it:

```
awk -F[\ =] '$0=$11||1'
```

If `$0=$11` yields zero/false, then the right hand side of the `||` (logical OR) operator gets evaluated and that is the value of the expression. Thus we ensure the expression always yields true so the print action takes place.

Answer (score 0):

The `sort` utility can sort the lines of the file without extracting the numbers.  You do this by describing to the utility what part of each line constitutes the sorting key.

```bsh
sort -t '=' -k 4,4n pingoutput.txt
```

The options used with `sort` above specify that the sorting key is the numeric value at the start of the fourth `=`-delimited field.

Would you want to get only the numbers from the result of the above command, then you may use `sed` to trim off everything up to the last equal sign on each line and then everything after the space.

```bsh
sort -t '=' -k 4,4n pingoutput.txt | sed -e 's/.*=//' -e 's/ .*//'
```

You may also do the operations in the opposite order.

```bsh
sed -e 's/.*=//' -e 's/ .*//' pingoutput.txt | sort -n
```

Use a redirection after any of the above commands to save the output to a file.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `sed` command to extract the related fields.
like

```
sed 's/.*time=\([0-9.]\+\).*/\1/p' test.log |sort

$ cat test.log
PING 10.74.88.113 (10.74.88.113) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.74.88.113: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=0.326 ms
64 bytes from 10.74.88.113: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=0.333 ms
64 bytes from 10.74.88.113: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=0.322 ms
64 bytes from 10.74.88.113: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=0.335 ms
64 bytes from 10.74.88.113: icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=0.337 ms
```

Comment: `\d` might no be supported. You should use `[0-9]`

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F\= '{print int($4)}' test | sort -n  > t
```